# How to select row data as column in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables like bellow shows figures

[image]

[image]

I need to select records as bellow shown figure. with AH_ID need to join in second table and ATT_ID will be the column header and ATT_DTL_STR_VALUE need to get as that column relevant value

Required output

[image]

Comment: What version of Oracle?  If you're using 11g, you could use the `PIVOT` operator.  In earlier versions, pivot queries were a bit more complex.  Do you know the set of `ATT_ID` values that you want to pivot at compile time?  Or does the query need to be dynamic?

Comment: Thank you justin can you send me sample code please

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  As I said, the code will be different for different versions.  Do you know the set of `ATT_ID` values that you want to pivot at compile time?

Comment: the oracle version is 9g . I am new in oracle Please send sample query

Comment: OK.  That answers my first question.  How about the second?

Comment: ATT_ID values will be dynamic

Comment: OK.  What language are you using to build the SQL statement dynamically, then?  Do you simply need to open a `REF CURSOR` in a stored procedure and return that to a calling program?  Or do you need to process the results in PL/SQL using the `DBMS_SQL` package?

Comment: i need to process result using PL/SQL in Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have an [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) data model which relational DBs [aren't the best at modeling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/607/what-is-a-key-value-store-database). You may want to look into a [key-value store](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/607/what-is-a-key-value-store-database).

However, as Justin suggested, if you're using 11g you can use th pivot clause as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT T1.AH_ID, T1.AH_DESCRIPTION, T2.ATT_ID, T2.ATT_DTL_STR_VALUE
      FROM T1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.AH_ID = T2.AH_ID
     )
PIVOT (MAX(ATT_DTL_STR_VALUE) FOR (ATT_ID) IN (1));
```

This statement requires you to hard-code in ATT_ID however there are ways to do it dynamically. More info can be found [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php).

Comment: @Wella if my answer was helpful please mark it as the accepted answer. Providing good feedback is an important part of the stackoverflow community. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: i'm try to find solution compatible with all the oracle version PIVOT can use on 11g, Also another problem is there i'm using dynamic ATT_ID values count of ATT_ID values can be very high because of that number of columns cannot be guess some time number of columns can be out of limit therefor i cannot use your solution in here but your suggestion is correct